# Sum values in the other columns for the 1st column with the same ID

Tags: awk

The input txt file looks like (there are more columns in the actual txt file):

```
target_id   length  eff_length  tot_counts  uniq_counts est_counts  eff_counts
mthl7   61  0   0   0   0   0
loqs    72  0   0   0   0   0
CG45085 58  0   0   0   0   0
CG18317 4978    1430.739479 91  0   30.333333   105.539363
CG18317 4978    1430.739479 91  0   30.333333   105.539363
CG18317 4978    1430.739479 91  0   30.333333   105.539363
```

for column 1 when they have the same id (e.g.CG18317) I want to add up the values in the rest of the columns. So the output would look like:

```
target_id   length  eff_length  tot_counts  uniq_counts est_counts  eff_counts
mthl7   61  0   0   0   0   0
loqs    72  0   0   0   0   0
CG45085 58  0   0   0   0   0
CG18317 14934   4292.218437 273 0   90.999999   316.618089
```

I tried to use command like:

```
awk -F" "
'{a[$1]+=$4;b[$1]+=$5;c[$1]+=$6;d[$1]+=$7;e[$1]+=$8;f[$1]+=$9;g[$1]+=$10;h[$1]+=$11;i[$1]+=$12;j[$1]+=$14;}END{for (i in a) print i" "a[i]" "b[i]" "c[i]" "d[i]" "e[i]" "f[i]" "g[i]" "h[i]" "i[i]" "j[i]}' temp2.txt
```

Error message is:

```
awk: can't assign to i; it's an array name.
 input record number 7, file temp2.txt
 source line number 1
```

Is this due to the header? How should I bypass the 1st row?

I tried answers for similar question found here but also did not work.

Comment: You can't use `i` for the iteration variable `for (i in a)` since it already refers to an array called `i` -  for example, what do you expect `i[i]` to return?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print;next} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1][i]+=$i}} END{ \
    for (j in a) {s=j; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {s=s" "a[j][i]}; print s}}' file
target_id   length  eff_length  tot_counts  uniq_counts est_counts  eff_counts
mthl7 61 0 0 0 0 0
loqs 72 0 0 0 0 0
CG18317 14934 4292.22 273 0 91 316.618
CG45085 58 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you want to keep the lines in the same order, it requires a little bit more code:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print;next} {if ($1 in seen); else b[c++]=$1; seen[$1]=1; \
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1][i]+=$i}} END{for (j=0;j<c;j++) {s=b[j]; \
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){s=s" "a[b[j]][i]}; print s}}' file | column -t
target_id  length  eff_length  tot_counts  uniq_counts  est_counts  eff_counts
mthl7      61      0           0           0            0           0
loqs       72      0           0           0            0           0
CG45085    58      0           0           0            0           0
CG18317    14934   4292.22     273         0            91          316.618
```

Above, we also piped the output to `column -t` to get aligned columns.

#### Commands in form suitable for copying and pasting

The above commands have been spread over multiple for easier viewer.  If you want to copy and past the commands, use these versions instead:

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1][i]+=$i}} END{ for (j in a) {s=j; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {s=s" "a[j][i]}; print s}}' file
```

And:

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} {if ($1 in seen); else b[c++]=$1; seen[$1]=1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1][i]+=$i}} END{for (j=0;j<c;j++) {s=b[j]; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){s=s" "a[b[j]][i]}; print s}}' file | column -t
```

#### Non-GNU `awk`

Try:

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} {if ($1 in seen); else b[c++]=$1; seen[$1]=1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1","i]+=$i}} END{for (j=0;j<c;j++) {s=b[j]; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){s=s" "a[b[j]","i]}; print s}}' file | column -t
```

Comment: Thanks again! I tried the second one. I got an error said: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 NR==1{print;next} {if ($1 in seen); else b[c++]=$1; seen[$1]=1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) >>>  {a[$1][ <<<

Comment: And the first one gave the same error.

Comment: @Karli Are you on OSX or another BSD platform?  The array-of-arrays feature seems to be what is causing that error and it is a GNU extension.  I will look for a work-around.

Comment: @Karli See updated answer.

Comment: I am on OSX, using bash4.2

Comment: the output seems the same as before, I mean the file stays the same no adding up.

Comment: @Karli Just to be clear, the file does not get changed in place: you should see the summed output on the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I mean the print out on terminal did not change. It is too long to paste in command...

Comment: And if I add > output.txt at the end the new file also did not change @John1024

Comment: @Karli The sample outputs shown in my answer were copied and pasted from actual output on the sample input.  At the moment I do not see how the code could possibly produce output unchanged from the input.  I will have to think about that.  Are you running it on the same sample input shown in the question?  Are the duplicated strings in the first column duplicated _exactly_?

Comment: Sorry, the difference is as I described in the question, there are more columns. One of the column is non numeric values...This is the problem? I tried to use code awk '{$13=""; print}' temp2.txt > temp3.txt to deleted that column first...but then result become empty values for all the columns except the id column...This is due to the 13th column I deleted become empty?

Comment: But if I use awk '{$13=""; sub(" ",""); print}' temp2.txt > temp3.txt to clear the empty line, somehow the "space" between id and the 2nd column is also gone so they become one column... @ John1024

Comment: Never mind. I was working around and it worked. I am no where close to cs related majors, so sorry for the problems...Thanks a lot for all the help! @John1024 P.S. I may need to post another question actually...

Comment: @Karli Glad you got it working.  If you post another question, I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted the other problem. Actually everything is for one script but different part of it...